# How can I change language to Russian in NA Steam version?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-7

For M&MH7 I can see Russian language supported with full audio on the [store page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/321960/Might__Magic_Heroes_VII/) :

[image: Store page has Russian]

However when I go to steam settings I can see all supported languages except for Russian:

[image: no Russian in steam]

The game is bought in North America steam store, I can also see it in my Uplay account, but no language preferences there.

Any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing [Unofficial Community Patch](https://www.moddb.com/mods/unoffical-community-mod-ucp), which has optional language packs. Unfortunately, it has translations only for text data, no audios are included.

And this patch also fixes some annoying bugs - like Vampires not being able to drain health. So it's better to install it anyway.